# Cannot plug bootstrap to my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on the project of another person. I have to install the bootstrap gem, but i cannot. i want to install it on the separate scss file. So, i'm doing this :

Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
```

My scss file

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/management.scss
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

my js file

```
#app/assets/javascripts/management.js
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

i call it in the layout like this

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "management", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "management" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
couldn't find file 'bootstrap-sprockets' with type 'application/javascript'
```

Comment: Did you try just `//= require bootstrap` in your js file?

Comment: yup, i get a new error : File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets., now in the scss file

Comment: Just to check: did you restart the server after `bundle`?

Comment: i restarted the server and got new error-message: `couldn't find file 'bootstrap-tooltip' with type 'application/javascript'`

Comment: And what if change to `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` again (now, after server restarting)?

Comment: just the same message `couldn't find file 'bootstrap-tooltip' with type 'application/javascript'`, but these `//= require bootstrap-tooltip` is located in my application.js

Comment: Try this: `//= require bootstrap/tooltip`

Comment: new error message `couldn't find file 'bootstrap-popover' with type 'application/javascript'`, but  writing `bootstrap/bootstrap-popover` does not work

Comment: `bootstrap/popover` not `bootstrap/bootstrap-popover`